# Why can we use time-dependent perturbations when evaluating the S-matrix?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, time-evolution, unitarity, s-matrix-theory

Suppose we have Hamiltonian $H_0 + V$. When working in the interaction picture we may derive the evolution operator of $|\psi_I(0)\rangle$ which is given by $$S(t,t_0) = T\left[\exp \left( -i \int_{t_0}^{t} V_I(t) dt \right) \right]$$
where $T$ is the time ordering symbol and $V_I$ is the interaction Hamiltonian in the interaction picture. This derivation seems to rely on the interaction part being constant in time in the Schrodinger picture, but it is immediately followed up by being used in a scenario where the interaction goes to zero at $t \to \pm \infty$ in the Schrodinger picture. I cannot reconcile this with the derivation. Can anyone help?

Comment: It seems you can derive this result without assuming $V$ is time independent, although not all books do this.

Comment: can you provide references? Schrodinger operators are defined to be time-independent.

Comment: @Kosm The book I am using is Many Body Physics by Piers Coleman. On page 88 onwards he derives the S matrix equation assuming that $V$ is constant. Then later in the driven Harmonic oscillator section on page 92, the interaction Hamiltonian is time-dependent.

Comment: I don't have that book. But the interaction Hamiltonian $V_S$ in the Schrodinger picture is time independent, like any other operator. The relation between $V_S$ and $V_I$ is $V_I=e^{iH_0t}V_Se^{-iH_0t}$. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @Kosm well the $V$ used (in the Schrodinger picture) is $V(t) = \bar{z}(t) b + b^\dagger z(t)$, which is time-dependent. Anyway, I realised one can obtain the same equation of motion for $U(t)$ even when $V$ is time dependent in the Schrodinger picture. Once you have this, you can work out the $S$ matrix.

Comment: i'm not sure how the Schrodinger picture is described there, but operators are defined to be time-independent is the S. picture, while states are time-dependent. In the Heisenberg picture, it's the opposite.

Comment: @Kosm hmm ok thank you. Well I do know that in the expression for $S$ in the book they used the relation $V_I = e^{iH_0 t} V_S e^{-i H_0 t}$, with $V_S$ being as I have given. Perhaps calling it Schrodinger picture is incorrect. However, can't we can have systems which can be approximated by time-dependent Hamiltonians that are presumably the same ''picture'' as the Schrodinger one?

Comment: I guess the main issue is that this is, as I mentioned, used in a scenario where in the ''distant'' past the interaction is off, then it is swtich on slowly, then swtiched off again into the ''distant'' future. I don't know how to reconcile the two.